# How to write controller for ng-include sidepanel.html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angularjs, We are using angularJs AMD.

index.html

```
<div ng-controller=“MainController">
    <div ng-include src="'sidepanel.html'"></div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
   'use strict';

define(['angularAMD', 'ui-router', 'ui_bootstrap', 'jquery-ui', 'angularModalService', 'bootstrapjs'], function (angularAMD) {
    var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularModalService']);

//Main Controller
    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$state', '$window',
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $state, $window) {
            $rootScope.sampleTest = 'Welcome Test';
        }]);
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
            $stateProvider.state('Home', {
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeController'
                    }
                }
            });
        }]);

// Bootstrap Angular when DOM is ready
    angularAMD.bootstrap(app);

    return app;
});
```

My problem is here.

How to write side panel controller here.

Sample github : https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD/tree/master/www

Comment: Why do you use ng-include instead of a custom directive ?

Comment: I have a sidepanel three li menus if i click that li menu i need to open one popup. Inside that popup we have dynamic links. the links are getting from service.